# what is the meaning of :MyInterfaceA<MyinterfaceB> myvariable in java?

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

Hi guys unsure of a line of code 
It look like the hierarchy below.

```
 public interface MyIntA<T extends MyIntB> {
   //stuff
}
```

and the second one

```
public interface MyIntB<T extends MyIntC>{
//stuff
}
```

and then in the else where in the code I see this

```
MyIntA<MyIntB> var = doStuff();
```

where doStuff(); has a return type of

```
<T extends MyIntB> MyIntA <T>
```

How is it that `MyIntA<MyIntB> var` is allowed ?
What type is var ? of type `Interface<Interface>` ?

Comment: Interface is not a "type"

Comment: ```MyIntA<MyIntB>```  is allowed because  ```public interface MyIntA<T extends MyIntB>```. where ```T``` is at least ```MyIntB``` ( Generic covariance). What seems to be the issue here

Comment: It takes some time to get comfortable with generics, so I understand your confusion. I don’t understand your concrete question. `var` is declared `MyIntA<MyIntB>`, so that is the compiletime type of `var` (since `MyIntA` is in interface, it will get a more specific runtime type).

Comment: The confusion was coming from this I suppose.
Lets say we have a variable its declared like so 

String myString ; 

Here the var myString is of type String.  

MyIntA<MyIntB> var  ; 

Here I thought it was of type interface --  which cant be instantiated .
Which is where the confusion came in I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you an existing example which may help you to understand-

We all use the `java.util.List`. `List` is an interface and following is the signature of `List`

```
public interface List <E> {
    void add(E x);
    Iterator<E> iterator();
    ...........
}
```

Now here `E` is the variable types which will be used in `List`. So when you are declaring a `List` variable with type `Integer` you are calling like following

```
List<Integer> list;
```

In your example the same thing is happening. You defining a `MyIntA` variable where you will use this variable for some type which extends `MyIntB`.

> What type is var ? of type Interface ?

`Interface` is not a type.. the type of `var` is the same as it is declared, which is `MyIntA<MyIntB>`

For more details you can check the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/simple.html)